# Highchart showing indicator at last point for line chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

[image: showing last point]

i know this can be achieve using jquery plugin *sparklines* but i'm more interested to manipulate highchartjs to achieve line chart as above where the blue dot is only showing on final point. Is there any special options to set?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

turn off marker on the series, then have to use an object instead of number for your last point.

demo here http://jsfiddle.net/4kxmb/

```
    series: [{
            name: 'Tokyo',
            marker: { enabled: false },  // turn off marker on every point
            data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, {
                y: 26.5,
                marker: {
                    enabled: true,  // turn on marker for last one
                    radius: 4,
                    symbol: 'circle'
                }
            }]

        }]
```